# How to "vlookup" like expert? Google Spreadsheet formula issue

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Stack! Please assist.
I have several columns with values that assigned to (let's say) "names". There is another one column with MASTER value that has to be multiplied on SUM of each value of unique name. Sounds not so clear as it is, please look through the table I've prepared to describe the issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18DAoXsb6Nz3UzxDG08BrpjltSNgzCBpKzlLBWzZWbpo/edit#gid=0

Example (for Jack):
Formula has to take "value X" of the name in "Unique names" and multiply it on "Value Y", for all "Jack" names and after that SUM values.
If formula works correctly, the final value for "jack" should be 0.6

Answer (score 1):

By rearranging arrays, We can use `SUMPRODUCT` do this:

B11:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({$D$2:$D$5;$F$2:$F$5;$H$2:$H$5}=A11)*{$C$2:$C$5;$E$2:$E$5;$G$2:$G$5}*{$A$2:$A$5;$A$2:$A$5;$A$2:$A$5})
```

In short:

```
 SUMPRODUCT (lookup factor *value x*value y)
```

A `ARRAYFORMULA`  version, as requested by OP:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--({$D$2:$D$5;$F$2:$F$5;$H$2:$H$5}=transpose(A11:A17))*{$C$2:$C$5;$E$2:$E$5;$G$2:$G$5}*{A$2:$A$5;A$2:$A$5;$A$2:$A$5}), ROW(A1:A12)^0))
```

Comment: OH! GREAT!! Thank you so much! It would be cool to add ARRAYFORMULA for big tables, is there any way to do it?

Comment: You are right! Thank you! sumproduct works better for me

Comment: @Slava, Check my edit. Also, Consider accepting my answer by clicking ☑ on the left of this post